# How to figure out if a file is a link?

Tags: c, linux, symlink, system-calls, stat

I have the below code *only a part of it is shown here* and I am checking if a the type of file.

```c
struct stat *buf /* just to show the type buf is*/ 

switch (buf.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
     case S_IFBLK:  printf(" block device\n");            break;
     case S_IFCHR:  printf(" character device\n");        break;
     case S_IFDIR:  printf(" directory\n");               break;
     case S_IFIFO:  printf(" FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
     case S_IFLNK:  printf(" symlink\n");                 break;
     case S_IFREG:  printf(" regular file\n");            break;
     case S_IFSOCK: printf(" socket\n");                  break;
     default:       printf(" unknown?\n");                break;
}
```

The problem: value of `st_mode` obtained when I do a `printf("\nMode: %d\n",buf.st_mode);` the result is 33188.

I tested my program with a regular file type and a symbolic link. In both cases the output was "regular file" i.e the symbolic link case is failing and I fail to understand why?

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Are you testing a symbolic link, and the program says it's a regular file? What's the value of buf.st_mode?

Comment: You need `lstat()`. `stat()` follows symbolic links and checks the files they point to.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [`stat (2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) man page:

> `stat()` stats the file pointed to by path and fills in `buf`.
>
> `lstat()` is identical to `stat()`, except that if path is a symbolic link, then the link itself is stat-ed, not the file that it refers to.

In other words, the `stat` call will follow the symbolic link to the target file and retrieve the information for *that.* Try using `lstat` instead, it will give you the information for the *link.*

---

If you do the following:

```
touch junkfile
ln -s junkfile junklink
```

then compile and run the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void) {
    struct stat buf;
    int x;

    x = stat ("junklink", &buf);
    if (S_ISLNK(buf.st_mode)) printf (" stat says link\n");
    if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)) printf (" stat says file\n");

    x = lstat ("junklink", &buf);
    if (S_ISLNK(buf.st_mode)) printf ("lstat says link\n");
    if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)) printf ("lstat says file\n");

    return 0;
}
```

you will get:

```
 stat says file
lstat says link
```

as expected.